# After weston server start up, run client immediately,the client can not be ran

Tags: linux, wayland

I write the command that start up weston and client sample simple-egl into a script like this:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib"
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/tmp"
mkdir -p XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
export GAL2D_DISPLAY=1
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/root/.config

weston&

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib"
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/tmp"

simple-egl &

The weston server can start,but the simple-egl can not run.

What's the reason ?

Comment: strace the binaries to see if they are finding the correct libraries and use LD_DEBUG

Comment: after the script ran, check XDG_RUNTIME_DIR,it is null.